# using a user defined function in place of cin in c++

Tags: c++

**What is the use of this function?**
I mean,the program where I saw this function,they used this in place of std input in c++,how does it work?

```
int scan()
{
    int n=0,ch =get();
    while(ch<'0'||ch>'9')
       ch = get();
    while(ch>='0'&& ch<='9')
    {
        n= n*10 +ch -'0';
        ch = get();
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: reads trash input, until you start entering digits, reads each digit until the input is not a digit and then returns the digits appended as an integer, i.e. if the input was "garbage334f", it would return 334.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly it reads the standart input until you type in some digits, then it returns the value composed of the digits after you type something different than a digit. It could be used to filter the first number in some input.